# Node-GDAL npm module, how to use Ogr2Ogr

Tags: node.js, gdal, ogr

I installed the npm module, GDAL, is the ogr2ogr utility bundled with the module or must I install additional npm modules?

Answer (score 1):

You must install the npm module "ogr2ogr" and the GDAL binaries (for OSX : http://scottdavey.net/article/Installing-GDAL-and-QGIS-on-OSX-Yosemite-231) then just run ogre -p 3000 in console